# How to play custom notification sound recorded by user and saved in ExternalStorageDirectory (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I am trying to play custom notification sound for a scheduled notification in Flutter but instead of using raw files sounds I need to get the sound from the External storage, like this path:

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.name.app/files/Sounds/audio.mp3

User can record him/her voice which is saved/converted to mp3 in that path. But I can’t manage to get that sound to be played in notification. My below code plays the default sound and ignores the mp3 files (btw I tried wav and mp3). My issue happens in Android part only, I have no problem with iOS while having the same recording be convefted to caf in Library/Sounds directory. Please see my android part:

```
              AndroidNotificationDetails(
                  'id_$timestamp', 'name_$timestamp', channelDescription: 'channel description',
                  sound: UriAndroidNotificationSound('file://$audioPath'),
                  playSound: true,
                  importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high
              );
```

Note that audiopath string is /storage/emulated………/file.mp3
Which is confirmed to be existing and checked to be played without any issue.

Appreciate your inputs.

I tried to use the recorded .wav file, and also tried to convert to mp3 using ffmpeg/lame and used both files paths and tried different schemes like file://path, content://path, andoird.resource://path with no luck. Always default sounds is being played.